# Good python library for generating audio files?

Tags: python, audio, mp3

Can anyone recommend a good library for generating an audio file, such as mp3, wav, or even midi, from python?

I've seen recommendations for working with the id tags (song name, artist, etc) in mp3 files, but this is not my goal.

Comment: It's important to note that MIDI is not audio. You only hear sound when MIDI is played back through something like a virtual instrument or synthesizer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/ and http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic, maybe some of the projects listed there can be of help.

Also, [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+audio+library).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but check out [ounk](http://code.google.com/p/ounk/).