# Python Music Library?

Tags: python, audio

I'm looking at writing a little drum machine in Python for fun.  I've googled some and found the python pages on [music](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) and [basic audio](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/) as well as a StackOverflow question on [generating audio files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385/good-python-library-for-generating-audio-files), but ***what I'm looking for is a decent library for music creation***.  Has anyone on here tried to do something like this before?  If so, what was your solution?  What, either of the ones I've found, or something I haven't found, would be a decent library for audio manipulation?

Minimally, I'd like to be able to do something similar to [Audacity's](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) scope within python, but if anyone knows of a library that can do more... I'm all ears.

Comment: potentially useful resources can be found also at http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Answer (score 14):

Take a close look at [cSounds](http://www.csounds.com/).  There are Python bindings allow you to do pretty flexible digital synthesis.  There are some pretty complete packages available, too.

See http://www.csounds.com/node/188 for a package.

See http://www.csounds.com/journal/issue6/pythonOpcodes.html for information on Python scripting within cSounds.

Answer (score 8):

I had to do this years ago. I used pymedia. I am not sure if it is still around any way here is some test code I wrote when I was playing with it. It is about 3 years old though.

**Edit:** The sample code plays an MP3 file

```
import pymedia
import time

demuxer = pymedia.muxer.Demuxer('mp3') #this thing decodes the multipart file i call it a demucker

f = open(r"path to \song.mp3", 'rb')


spot = f.read()
frames = demuxer.parse(spot)
print 'read it has %i frames' % len(frames)
decoder = pymedia.audio.acodec.Decoder(demuxer.streams[0]) #this thing does the actual decoding
frame = decoder.decode(spot)
print dir(frame)
#sys.exit(1)
sound = pymedia.audio.sound
print frame.bitrate, frame.sample_rate
song = sound.Output( frame.sample_rate, frame.channels, 16 ) #this thing handles playing the song

while len(spot) > 0:
    try:
        if frame: song.play(frame.data)
        spot = f.read(512)
        frame = decoder.decode(spot)
    except:
        pass

while song.isPlaying(): time.sleep(.05)
print 'well done'
```

Comment: PyMedia is indeed still around.  Does this sample play a given mp3 file?  It might be good to note what it does, just to clarify the answer a bit.

Answer (score 4):

There is a variety of Python music software, you can find a catalog [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic).

If you scroll down the linked page, you find a section on **Music Programming in Python** describing several music creation packages including [MusicKit](http://musickit.sourceforge.net/) and [PySndObj](http://sndobj.sourceforge.net/#python).

Comment: Have you worked with either of these, or are you just reading from the feature list?

Answer (score 3):

Also check out http://code.google.com/p/pyo/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been mentioned previously, I wrote a simple Python audio editor.
http://code.google.com/p/yaalp/source/browse/#svn/trunk
See main.py.

It also has audio manipulation and some effects.

Code's GPL, so this could be a starting point for you.