# Good Sound processing/Analysis/Capturing Modules

Tags: python, audio

We are working on Sound processing and Analysis where we need to extract frequencies, pitches, octaves and other parameters of sound including dBPowerSpectrum Analysis.

We also need to do this irrespective of the file formats or do the conversion between quite a file format(though conversion is not a very critical requirement if those parameters can be analyzed on most file formats).
We also need to capture/record sound from Mic. We found a Python module called Snack which does almost everything we need, but the whole problem is that it requires tkinter to be installed.
Since we are planning to write a Web client for this program, I feel installing tkinter and initializing and passing its object to Sound Processing module is an overhead.
Can you please suggest us few good Sound Processing Module. We don't expect an all in one module. Its OK even if these functionalities are spread over several modules.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108848/python-music-library

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.csounds.com/node/188 for a package that does much of this.

Answer (score 2):

For audio capture and playback I've liked [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/). It's cross-platform and pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scikits audiolab](http://cournape.github.com/audiolab/) to read in any file supported by [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/), and then use [PyLab](http://www.scipy.org/PyLab) ([NumPy and SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/)) to do the processing.

I don't know of a way to read in live audio from the mic, though, which is why I was just looking at Snack myself.  If there's a way to convert Snack sounds into numpy arrays, then that would work.

If you use `padsp ipython` in Ubuntu, you can read in data from /dev/dsp, and it will actually be coming from PulseAudio's input.  You can use the [ossaudiodev](http://docs.python.org/library/ossaudiodev.html) module, though I haven't gotten this to work, or you can do some kind of ugly construction like:

```
audio = numpy.fromfile('/dev/dsp'...
```

but I guess you still need to use ossaudiodev to set up the sampling rate, format, etc. first.