# How do I do mathematical analysis on microphone audio information from pyaudio?

Tags: python, audio, microphone, pyaudio

I am trying to obtain the pitch, the level, and other stuff from my microphone using Python. I am trying using pyaudio, but I read that I need to use other libraries to generate the maths. I can’t find how mix pyaudio with the math library.

Comment: Which math library are you trying to use? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: When you did this search, what did you find? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+audio+processing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Sound processing/Analysis/Capturing Modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519851/good-sound-processing-analysis-capturing-modules)

Answer (score 0):

I have performed basic signal processing (FFT etc) using numpy/scipy directly on the audio buffer without too much trouble. Be careful, you need to tell numpy about the buffer type: float or int, long or short, signed/unsigned ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Python module `audioop` to determine the power/loudness of an audio sample, with the [`audioop.rms`](http://docs.python.org/library/audioop#audioop.rms) function.