# In Python, how do you play musical notes?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Music Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108848/python-music-library)

Is there a way to play musical notes in Python? Also setting duration would be useful.  If there are any built-in modules for it then that will be great, but if there is an outside module I need to download that is also fine.

If anyone can post exact examples that would be helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: Step 1.  Search for "Python and Music".  Step 2.  Read the links.  Step 3.  Update your question to be more specific.  This has been asked here, and a great deal of information is available through Google.

Comment: @S.Lott I've been struggling to find a solution for this, no luck in last two days. Though great deal of info is available through google.

Answer (score 5):

Look here for many audio libraries: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

You probably want MusicKit.

Answer (score 4):

The Python standard library includes the [winsound](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html) module, which allows you to play tones with a specific frequency and duration on Windows platforms.

Comment: Only Windows platforms? That is better than nothing, but I prefer to make it crossplatform. Is there a module I can download which allows me to make it cross-platform?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/f-rumblefish/4b8bff2791a7ee61c8087b75f30a3a23

Comment: winsound is great, but there is a gap between two consucutive beeps

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question I have never thought about doing this before. From a quick search it looks like http://musickit.sourceforge.net/ or http://sndobj.sourceforge.net/ are good solutions. I will look into it more.